# How to avoid Immutable.JS functions/accessors inside React components

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, immutable.js

I'm coding an application using React for UI, Redux to manage the state and Immutable.js to mutate the state, however, I'd like to know **how to avoid the use of Immutable.JS accessors in my React components**, like **get()** or **getIn()**.

I believe that using that Immutable.JS accessors will infect my React components. How to avoid that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to avoid Immutable.JS accessors and use the dot-notation is using the Record structure from Immutable.JS.

First we must create a template:

```
const MyTemplate = Record({
  id: 0,
  name: ''
})
```

...

```
case ContentFilterTypes.ADD_ITEM:
    return {
        listObjects : state.listObjects.push(new MyTemplate({
            id: action.item.id,
            name: action.item.description,
        }))
    }
```

To access it in the presentional, we need only to set the prop that we want to get information, like:

```
<ContentFilterAvatar id={value.id} name={value.name} />
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you're going to have much in the way of an option here if you want to keep it immutable. You could convert it `toJS`, but then you'd be losing the benefits of object identity comparison for re-rendering pure components. Your best bet is probably to hold your nose and pretend it's basically a [JavaScript Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).

Aside from that, if you're not attached to Immutable.js, you might consider using something like [seamless immutable](https://github.com/rtfeldman/seamless-immutable) which behaves a lot more like native JavaScript arrays and objects. Or you could go old-fashioned and just [`Object.freeze()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) things yourself.